# SQL Getting count of distinct rows for each value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I don't have much experience to SQL, and I can't seem to figure out this problem.

If I have a table like this:

**Installs**

```
id   user
1    bob
2    carl
2    carl
2    charles
3    bill
3    bill
```

and another like this:

**Apps**

```
id   name
1    app1
2    app2
3    app3
```

How would I get something like this?:

```
name   distinct_users
app1   1
app2   2
app3   1
```

I have tried this:

```
select apps.name, count(distinct installs.user) 
from installs, apps 
where installs.id = apps.id;
```

but that only yields one row because it is counting the total number of distinct users in installs.

```
app1 4
```

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. This may prove problematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `group by` clause to get result **per app**:

```
SELECT   apps.name, COUNT(distinct installs.user) 
FROM     installs, apps 
WHERE    installs.id = apps.id;
GROUP BY apps.name
```

Note, by the way, the implicit joins (having more than one table in the `from` clause have been considered to be deprecated for quite a while now. Instead, it's recommended you use an explicit join:

```
SELECT   apps.name, COUNT(distinct installs.user) 
FROM     installs
JOIN     apps ON installs.id = apps.id;
GROUP BY apps.name
```

Answer (score 2):

Use group by and count(*)

```
Select apps.name, count(*) 
from installs 
inner join  apps  on  installs.id = apps.id
group by apps.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `GROUP BY`.
More over avoid comma separated table concepts and use JOIN with ON.
Add alias name for each table to the better readability.

```
SELECT A.name, COUNT(DISTINCT I.user) 
FROM apps A
INNER JOIN installs I ON I.id = A.id
GROUP BY A.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `apps`.`name`, COUNT(DISTINCT(`installs`.`user`)) 
FROM `installs`, `apps` 
WHERE `installs`.`id` = `apps`.`id`
GROUP BY `apps`.`id`;
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79ed7/1).

Comment: I in fact upvoted you, two other people must have downvoted. Your answer was helpful, thanks.

Comment: @User9123 thank you sir for just replying, my comment is not for you, i had one more query in my answer that was removed because it was wrong. I removed it 5 minutes after i posted it since i was not fetching correct results. I just can't undestand why (when only this query was left) would someone down-vote something that works!